Troubleshooting Issues with Android Emulator on Vs Code
I am new to Flutter
I select the device in vs Code to start coding it open and it goes immediately I don't know why and this error shows in the terminal
[ERR] The Android emulator exited with code -1073741819 after startup
[ERR] Android emulator stderr:
[ERR] [21964:13432:20240525,102936.149:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\azzed\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.14.db\attachments\cb19c8a3-b01f-46b9-a19b-be02673f0991: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [15220:22804:20240525,102936.770:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\azzed\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.14.db\attachments\cb19c8a3-b01f-46b9-a19b-be02673f0991: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address: a86f:678d:6c02:0:504e:678d:6c02:0 (2x)
[ERR] WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\azzed\.android\avd\..\avd\Pixel_7_API_33.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
[ERR] cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
[ERR] WARNING | The emulator now requires a signed jwt token for gRPC access! Use the -grpc flag if you really want an open unprotected grpc port
[ERR] WARNING | *** Basic token auth should only be used by android-studio ***
[ERR] netsimd I 05-25 09:29:42.605 rust_main.rs:96 - netsim artifacts path: "C:\\Users\\azzed\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\netsimd"
[ERR] netsimd I 05-25 09:29:42.605 rust_main.rs:99 - NetsimdArgs {
[ERR]     fd_startup_str: None,
[ERR]     no_cli_ui: true,
[ERR]     no_web_ui: true,
[ERR]     pcap: false,
[ERR]     disable_address_reuse: false,
[ERR]     hci_port: None,
[ERR]     connector_instance: None,
[ERR]     instance: None,
[ERR]     logtostderr: false,
[ERR]     dev: false,
[ERR]     vsock: None,
[ERR]     config: None,
[ERR]     test_beacons: false,
[ERR]     no_test_beacons: false,
[ERR]     no_shutdown: false,
[ERR]     version: false,
[ERR] }
[ERR] WARNING | Device 'cache' does not have the requested snapshot 'default_boot'
[ERR] WARNING | Failed to load snapshot 'default_boot'
[ERR] [15220:22804:20240525,103008.091:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\azzed\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.14.db\attachments\bf58cf72-208e-47ed-88e8-5b9441a1807b: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [15220:22804:20240525,103008.096:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\azzed\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.14.db\attachments\bf58cf72-208e-47ed-88e8-5b9441a1807b: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] [15220:22804:20240525,103008.151:ERROR filesystem_win.cc:130] GetFileAttributes C:\Users\azzed\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.14.db\attachments\bf58cf72-208e-47ed-88e8-5b9441a1807b: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
[ERR] Address these issues and try again.

I try to use my phone as a device to see the result in it but it doesn't work

This could be due to various reasons, try these points... run emulator outside VS Code, restart your computer, check antivirus/firewall might be blocking the emulator, clear emulator cache, update android emulator.
